# How to connect laptop to TV using a VGA cable and a 3 RCA cable

Tags: system-settings, vga, tv

I would like step by step instructions showing me exactly how to do it especially with pictures to show me where the cables connect to. I don't know what goes where and what program I need to connect a TV to a laptop to watch my movies.

Comment: VGA (RGB) signalling is different from RCA component (Y,Cr,Cb or Y/Pb/Pr - check which is supported by your TV) signaling. You need a special converter box. Google "vga to rca" for more information. BTY you are off-topic :-)

Answer (score 2):

***VGA***

VGA or **Video Graphic Array** output has separate (Component) colour outputs. It has separate outputs for Red, Green, Blue colours.

Also it doesn't have audio output.

[image]

***RGB***

RGB or **Red, Green, Blue** cables have one (Composite) video line while having two stereo audio lines. Even though it is called red, green, blue, it doesn't have separate video lines.

[image]

So VGA output needs to be converted into one or **Composite** line before it's connected to a RGB or RCA cable.

Such a converter is called a **VGA to Composite converter** or Component to Composite converter. You need to have a VGA to Composite converter for your purpose.